# Extract digits from python string

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract digits from a python string into key value pairs.

Original string is `TOTAL Earnings 117,050.00` or
`WCPS Contribution -1,671.00` want the result to be `{'TOTAL Earnings': 117050}` or `{'WCPS Contribution': -1671}`

Comment: what have you tried  ?

Comment: We need more context here.  Please show the examples inside a larger text.  Your current code might also help.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string and convert it to dict:

```
s='TOTAL Earnings 117,050.0'
l=s.rsplit(' ',1)
l[1]=int(float(l[1].replace(',','')))
d=dict([l])
```

Result:

```
{'TOTAL Earnings': 117050}
```

Comment: I don't think the OP would want to convert the numbers to `int`s. Even though the examples given show `00` for the decimal component, that's not necessarily the case in general. Probably best to keep as `float`

Comment: Well, then the desired output should have shown this. Anyway, it's trivial to adapt